# como editar um array em angular

Tags: angularjs, arraylist

Olá sou novo em js e angular e estou tentando editar um array onde guardo tarefas a serem desenvolvidas. Tenho as seguintes funções para adicionar e excluir os elementos, porem não consigo pensar uma maneira para editar minhas tarefas apos cadastradas.

Tenho o seguinte código ate o momento:

Html

  
    
       
       {{app}}

```
    <tr ng-class="{selecionado: item.selecionado}" ng-repeat="item in tarefas">
      <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selecionado"></td>
      <td >{{item.titulo}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</hr>
<form ng-submit="adicionarTarefa(item)">
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="item.titulo" placeholder="Escrever nova tarefa.." ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && (adicionarTarefa)"/>
```

Apagar tarefa

```
//Meu array

$scope.tarefas = [
    {
        titulo: "Fazer o documento do carro",
        descricao: "Ano 2015, 2016 e 2017",
        hora: "28/11/2017"
    },
    {
        titulo: "Solicitar emprestimo bancario",
        descricao: "Ano 2015, 2016 e 2017",
        hora: "28/11/2017"
    }
];

//Comportamento do ng click - Cadastro tarefas

    $scope.adicionarTarefa = function(item){
      $scope.tarefas.push(angular.copy(item));
    };

  //Comportamento do ng click - Apagar tarefas
      $scope.apagarTarefa = function(tarefas){
        $scope.tarefas = tarefas.filter(function(item){
          if (!item.selecionado) return item;
        });
      };

});
```

Comment: Se você fizer o `bindig` do item que quer editar em controle `html`, ele irá atualizar o item assim que você alterar na página, não precisa escrever código específico pra isso. Algo assim já funcionaria: `<input type='text' ng-model='tarefas[0].titulo' />`, nesse exemplo editando o primeiro item do seu `array`

Comment: Quando você diz "editar", quer dizer adicionar/remover (como já está fazendo) ou modificar o conteúdo de cada item do array?